# Facebook Access Token - Comment as Site

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, token

I have a big Problem, i search since days a Solution for my Problem. Maybe here someone can help me.

I need a Access Token for my Fanpage. I know i need manage_page rule.
I also have create a App. With ID and Secret ID.

My Problem is when i use the Token it post as Admin not as Site. And the post on the Fanpage must be as Site.

I Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

If it posts as user/admin and not as Page, you are most likely using a User Access Token. If you want to post as Page, you need to use a **Page Access Token** with the `publish_actions` permission: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed#publish

Some Links about creating Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/